# Grouping query results by Month through date stamp in the row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have made a query which shows all hits recorded for a particular region. It goes something like this:

### Unique Visits by Region

```
SELECT
         r.field_region_for_real_value as region,  Count(*) as count
        FROM
          login_activity l, users u, field_data_field_region_for_real r
        where l.uid = u.uid AND u.uid = r.entity_id

        Group by r.field_region_for_real_value
```

*The results of this are as follows:*

```
region       |  count
----------------------
Asia              23
EEMA              14
Latin America     73
North America     61
Western Europe    47
```

But now what I am trying to do is to change the way this data is represented. I am hoping that instead of grouped by `region`, it is grouped by month. Within the month, I am hoping to have all values of each region that have a data falling in that month.

For example, here is the result I am hoping to achieve:

```
    month          |   Asia    |   EEMA    |   Latin America    |   North America    |   Western Europe 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan                23         43              23                  43                    53           
    Feb                63         3               13                  39                    18 
    Mar                23         39              42                  29                    17
    Apr                49         56              50                  64                    98
    May                63         3               13                  39                    18
    Jun                21         92              15                  23                    19
    Jul                49         56              50                  64                    98
    Aug                63         3               13                  39                    18
    Sep                63         3               13                  39                    18
    Oct                23         39              42                  29                    17
    Nov                23         43              23                  43                    53
    Dec                21         92              15                  23                    19
```

The date which needs to be processed comes from the table `login_activity`. The fields of the table are as follows:

```
aid              int .  (Unique ID)
uid              int
hostname         varchar
timestamp        int    (Date)
```

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us. As for the rest, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I understand :) but the data has to come through query as this needs to be extracted on the go

Comment: This is a frequent question on SO. Try googling mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation and heres some links to start you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Extracted on the go? Extracted by what? For what? Humans care about display formats. Computers generally don't.

Comment: What I meant was that I have to extract this data from the sql query

Comment: any assistance here please